# Insert delimiters into Python mixed-type list

Tags: python

I have a list composed of strings and numbers, e.g.:

```
list = ["aa","bb",100,"cc",200,300]
```

I want to construct a newlist with a delimiter inserted between each list element:

```
newlist = ["aa","|","bb","|",100,"|","cc","|",200,"|",300]
```

Something like

```
insert = "|"
newlist = [x + insert for x in list]
```

doesn't work because of the non-string elements in the list. There's got to be something other than what I'm doing though:

```
arg[0] + "|" + arg[1] + "|" +
```

etc. Suggestions?

Comment: The duplicate has plenty of options, here is one: `[val for pair in zip(list_, ['|' for _ in list_]) for val in pair][:-1]`  I would also avoid using `list` as a variable name, as it overrides a builtin.

Comment: Most excellent, @user3483203, thank you. I'm not seeing a way to accept your answer, however.